# inf answer when using while loops in python to calculate balances

Tags: python, while-loop

I have to write a program that calculates Balkcom's and Brissie's balances using while-loop and then print the first year where Balkcom's balance surpasses Brissie's

**The problem is that when I run the program it gives me inf as the answers for both balances, is there a way to fix this or is there another way to do it using while-loops?**

**Important info:**

Balkcom initial deposit: 1

Brissie initial deposit: 100000

Balkcom interest rate: 5%

Brissie interest rate: 4%

```
#Define constant & variables
BALKCOM_INI_DEPOSIT = 1
BALKCOM_INT_RATE = 1.05
BRISSIE_INI_DEPOSIT = 100000
BRISSIE_INT_RATE = 104000
balkcom_balance = BALKCOM_INI_DEPOSIT * BALKCOM_INT_RATE
brissie_balance = BRISSIE_INI_DEPOSIT * BRISSIE_INT_RATE
year = 0

sys.set_int_max_str_digits(100000)

while balkcom_balance < brissie_balance:                    
    balkcom_balance = balkcom_balance * BALKCOM_INT_RATE    
    brissie_balance = brissie_balance * BRISSIE_INT_RATE
    year = year + 1

print("Year:", year, " " + "Balkcom balance:", balkcom_balance, "Brissie balance:", brissie_balance)
```

Comment: 104000 is a ridiculously large interest rate. What are you trying to compute? `float` cannot represent arbitrarily large values; eventually, `x * 104000` is going to be bigger than that value, resulting in (`float`'s idea of) infinity. (For that matter, so will `x * 1.05`, but it will take much longer.)

Comment: Even if you had an arbitrary-precision floating-point type, `balkcom_balance` is *always* going to be smaller, since it is smaller to begin with and grows at a slower rate than `brissie_balance`.

Comment: With `BRISSIE_INT_RATE = 1.04`, things would get more interesting. How long will it take a much smaller balance to exceed a much larger balance with even a slightly larger growth rate?

Comment: I tried 1.04 for Brissie_int_rate and it gives year 1203 and actual numbers in the balances

Comment: Thank you I was actually wrong about the interest rate!